# show repeated data in custom way in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am working on Angularjs application where I need loop through data to show in customized way

I have modified html now its working almost now only problem is `Key` is string value concatenated by comma of  `entityName,appointmentName` .
How do I show these two values on different places ??

Comment: [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)  will do exactly that.

Comment: Why don't you use ng-repeat? Repeat entityName in entityNames, then, you associate a date to them.

Comment: Yes I can use that but how can I achieve this customized output where entityname and  appointmentName are same then don't repeat them show them once with multiple eventname and duedate

Answer (score 0):

You could definitely go with ng-repeat https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: I have updated data in question , please have a look . Now problem is Key.. its string concatenated by comma of  entityName,appointmentName. How do i get separate value of these two ?